How to properly incorporate jinja unique_id field in openai prompt
I am running an client ingestion where I look to OpenAI to give me specific field back from a payload as well as providing the regex for the unique_id when passed in. The issue that I am running up against is when asking for the regex for the unique_id field it always passed the same string [^:]+$. I know it's wrong because the unique_id can change depending on the client. For example, for this particular client_id the unique_id is US::513::12345678. For another client the unique_id is US::222::first_name:last_name:12345678. Specically, I am only looking for the regex after the final two colons. When manually pulling the regex for US::513::12345678 it's \d{8}$ and for US::222::first_name:last_name:12345678 it's [^:]+:[^:]+:\d{8}$. When rendering the prompt I check for the following pattern, unique_id.split('::')[-1]
The prompt I'm running is as follows:
{
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are an expert at identifying identifiers within json data. Your job is to examine a sample of 10 json payloads and extract keys that correspond to the following elements: - Member Identifier. In each json payload, there is a field that uniquely identifies a member. - Primary Member Identifier. In each json payload, there is a field that allows you to determine the unique identifier of the primary member or primary subscriber. - Health coverage start date. In each json payload, there is a field that allows you to determine the date of the member's health coverage start date. - Member date of birth. In each json payload, there is a field that allows you to determine the member's date of birth. The fields you identify must contain data (must not be empty). You must only respond with a list of four integers each denoting the key number from the json payload that corresponds to each element. Along with that provide the regex_contains code for the unique identifier."
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "These are the 10 json payloads: 
            {%- for sample in samples -%}
            {{ sample }}{{ "," if not loop.last else "" }}
            {%- endfor -%}
            The unique identifier part is: {{ unique_value }}."
        }

The python code that looks render this prompt is the following:
def render_prompt(self, samples: List[Dict[str, str]], unique_id: str) -> dict:
        if not samples:  # Check if samples is empty
            return {}  # Return an empty dictionary if no samples

        unique_value = unique_id.split('::')[-1]

        samples_as_json = [json.dumps(p['payload']).replace('"', '').replace("\\", '') for p in samples]
        jinja_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("./predict_llm/prompts"))
        template = jinja_env.get_template("prompt_base.j2")

        try:
            # Render the template with the samples
            rendered_json = template.render(samples=samples_as_json, unique_value=unique_value)

            # with open("test.json", "w") as f:
            #     f.write(rendered_json)

            return json.loads(rendered_json)  # Ensure it's valid JSON
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Error rendering JSON: {e}")

What gets returned when running the code in full is this:
{"513": "The keys corresponding to the required elements in the JSON payloads are as follows:\n\n1. Member Identifier: `Member ID`\n2. Primary Member Identifier: `Contract Holder Member ID`\n3. Health coverage start date: `Coverage Effective Date`\n4. Member date of birth: `DOB`\n\nThe regex pattern to match the unique identifier (Member ID) is:\n```regex\n\\[^:]+$\n```"}

I'm expecting this:
{"513": "The keys corresponding to the required elements in the JSON payloads are as follows:\n\n1. Member Identifier: `Member ID`\n2. Primary Member Identifier: `Contract Holder Member ID`\n3. Health coverage start date: `Coverage Effective Date`\n4. Member date of birth: `DOB`\n\nThe regex pattern to match the unique identifier (Member ID) is:\n```regex\n\\d{8}$\n```"}

